# Drag and drop web builder?

Tags: html, design

I'm not that experienced with HTML coding, is there any free drag and drop builder I can use and get the files from it that way I can host a website on a ubuntu machine?

Comment: What you are looking for is a WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) editor. From what I know, the options are limited in Ubuntu. But if all you are after is a SIMPLE webpage, you could use Libreoffice Writer and save your document as a HTML file and post that.

If you need more than a SIMPLE webpage, then this is the wrong place to ask. :)

P.S. Did you notice the word "SIMPLE" ??? :)